# Ubuntu installation on Windows 10 Fails

Tags: 14.04, windows-10

I have a fresh Windows 10 system with BIOS. I downloaded latest 64bit Ubuntu 14.04.03 and then run the installation file(Wubi), it asks me to reboot to boot from CD Drive,which I don't have. When reboot, after the initial message, it keeps busy for a while and then exits with following error:

```
Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
ACPI PCC probe failed.
Unable to find a medium containing a live file system
```

I tried to install and run from USB drive, but same issue.
Can you help with this please?

Comment: Hi Arash, for the installation to work you need to run the installer from withing a LiveCD / LiveUSB and not from Wubi. No installer will work using Wubi (Wubi is also deprecated  since about 2 years ago). Follow this answer even though it is UEFI based. The same principle applies for you http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi?lq=1

Comment: Wubi has been [deprecated](/q/448686/175814) for years and doesn't work with Windows 10 in UEFI mode. Please [install Ubuntu as a stand-lone OS alongside Windows](/q/221835/175814)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Windows based utility called RUFUS located at http://rufus.akeo.ie.  You may want to try using this to burn the Ubuntu .iso file to a USB stick.  Once you this done you enter the BIOS of your system and change the boot order so that the USB stick is the first boot device.  This should allow you to boot into the Ubuntu live CD.  From there you should be able to install Ubuntu

Comment: Another option would be to use virtual box from within Windows to try Ubuntu before actually installing directly to your hardware.